# PHP Function to split a combined CSS attribute/value to several attributes

Tags: php, css, stylesheet

Basically, I want this:

```
h2 {
    font: bold 36px/2em "Times New Roman"
}
```

To this:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-family: "Times New Roman"
}
```

And other variations, of course. Does anyone know of a function that does this so I don't have to code it myself? :)

Comment: I'd like to have a function that does the inverse..

Comment: @Alix Axel: Yup that is better choice and more logical :)

Comment: Yes, I would like it to manage both ways, of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this **[CSS Shorthand for the Font Element](http://www.seifi.org/css/css_shorthand_for_the_font_element.html)**:

[image: CSS Font Shorthand Style Guide]

I've come up with the following regular expression:

```
font:(?:\s+(inherit|normal|italic|oblique))?(?:\s+(inherit|normal|small-caps))?(?:\s+(inherit|normal|bold(?:er)?|lighter|[1-9]00))?(?:\s+(\d+(?:%|px|em|pt)?|(?:x(?:x)?-)?(?:small|large)r?)|medium|inherit)(?:\/(\d+(?:%|px|em|pt)?|normal|inherit))?(?:\s+(inherit|default|.+?));?$
```

Obtained from these smaller regular expressions:

```
$font['style'] = '(?:\s+(inherit|normal|italic|oblique))?';
$font['variant'] = '(?:\s+(inherit|normal|small-caps))?';
$font['weight'] = '(?:\s+(inherit|normal|bold(?:er)?|lighter|[1-9]00))?';
$font['size'] = '(?:\s+(\d+(?:%|px|em|pt)?|(?:x(?:x)?-)?(?:small|large)r?)|medium|inherit)';
$font['height'] = '(?:\/(\d+(?:%|px|em|pt)?|normal|inherit))?';
$font['family'] = '(?:\s+(inherit|default|.+?))';
```

**Usage:**

```
$regex = 'font:' . implode('', $font) . ';?$';    
$matches = array();
$shorthand = 'font: bold 36px/2em Arial, Verdana, "Times New Roman";';

if (preg_match('~' . $regex . '~i', $shorthand, $matches) > 0)
{
    echo '<pre>';    
    if (strlen($matches[1]) > 0) { // font-style is optional
        print_r('font-style: ' . $matches[1] . ';' . "\n");
    }

    if (strlen($matches[2]) > 0) { // font-variant is optional
        print_r('font-variant: ' . $matches[2] . ';' . "\n");
    }

    if (strlen($matches[3]) > 0) { // font-weight is optional
        print_r('font-weight: ' . $matches[3] . ';' . "\n");
    }

    print_r('font-size: ' . $matches[4] . ';' . "\n"); // required

    if (strlen($matches[5]) > 0) { // line-height is optional
        print_r('line-height: ' . $matches[5] . ';' . "\n");
    }

    print_r('font-family: ' . $matches[6] . ';' . "\n"); // required
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 2em;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, "Times New Roman";

Array
(
    [0] => font: bold 36px/2em Arial, Verdana, "Times New Roman";
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => bold
    [4] => 36px
    [5] => 2em
    [6] => Arial, Verdana, "Times New Roman"
)
```

This is meant for extraction not validation since it accepts stuff like xx-smaller (which isn't valid).

To make the expanded version you can either use `preg_match()` or `preg_replace()`, although using the latter would be more difficult to "ignore" unused declarations.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look further into this!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in PHP. You could create such a function - I would start with a map that contains [styleRuleName => [{sets of valid attributes}]] for each shorthand selector you wish to expand. I think you'll find this to be a bit of a nightmare to code though.

Comment: Of course there is no built in function, I meant a third-party function. I could obviously code it myself, but I don't want to :)

Comment: Not aware of such a third party function either. Most people are concerned with combining attributes, not expanding them.